# Can't add values to the points inside a chart form in c#

Tags: c#, charts, datatable

Good morning everyone,

I'm in the middle of creating a chart from a variable DataTable in C#. I have seen different sample codes and I tried to apply everything but I can't see the data reflected in my chart. This is the code I have made to fill my chart with data:

```
//Aggregates the series - For our app we're using from the third to the last column generated from the datatable used for our chart.
for (i = 2; i < myAux.Columns.Count; i++)
{
    this.chartReport.Series.Add(myAux.Columns[i].ColumnName);
}

//Assigns the value of the XAxis according to the name of the first column from our datatable assigned to the datasource of the chart.
for (i = 0; i < this.chartReport.Series.Count; i++)
{
    this.chartReport.Series[i].XValueMember = myAux.Columns[0].ColumnName;
    this.chartReport.Series[i].YValueMembers = myAux.Columns[1].ColumnName;
    this.chartReport.Series[i].ChartType = System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.SeriesChartType.Bar;
}

//Add values X and Y to the chart
for (i = 1; i < myAux.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    int m = 0;
    for (j = 2; j < myAux.Columns.Count; j++)
    {
        this.chartReport.Series[m].Points.Add(Convert.ToDouble(myAux.Rows[i][j].ToString()));
        m++;
    }
}
```

Inside my code, the variable `myAux` is a datatable created with the parameters give by the user, I use it as a copy of the main table that shows the report data made previously by the user.

I dunno what I miss here, but I'm sure that it's what it's avoiding to show the bars of my chart. If someone has an idea, I would appreciate the answer quite a lot because I am stuck for a couple of days with this!

Thanks a lot in advance.

**EDIT:** I found one part of the problem: If I comment the second for in my code it brings data, but now I have a problem because I can't show what's in my XAxis and in my YAxis. If you have any idea what I should do I would appreciate it a lot!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found what the problem was... I was assigning the wrong values between the series and the YAxis values. So what I did was changing the whole creation and assignation:

```
//Aggregates the series - For our app we're using from the third to the last column generated from the datatable used for our chart.
Series mySerie = new Series();
mySerie.Name = myAux.Columns[1].ColumnName;
mySerie.XValueMember = myAux.Columns[0].ColumnName;

for (i = 2; i < myAux.Columns.Count; i++)
{
    mySerie.YValueMembers = myAux.Columns[i].ColumnName;
}

this.chartReport.Series.Add(mySerie);
```

With this I solved the whole problem of the values that didn't appear. Now I have to work on the presentation of the chart :)

Answer (score 0):

I think I might know whats wrong.
The series are never created. first create a series for your chart. Note each series should be created.

```
mychart.Series[0] = new Series("MySeries");
```

Comment: I thought that with `this.chartReport.Series.Add(myAux.Columns[i].ColumnName);` was enough. Still... I added the line to create the series but still can't see my data inside of the chart :(

Comment: oops. Sorry I missed Series.Add... I was without coffee for too long. Series.Add is fine. What I did not see however is     chartReport.ChartAreas.Add("MyChartArea"); //this should be done just after your chart is created.

Comment: I used the default ChartArea created at the moment I created the object. The error from the data was with the second for. I commented it in my code and now I get the data. But now I have a new problem: I would like to use as my AxisX different dates, but I can't find a way to display it.

Comment: I worked with charts a few weeks ago, I see nothing else that could be wrong. Looking through my previous works. Is all to similar. I never used Points.Add(). I used points.AddXY. Does the data convert to double successfully ?   For AxisX dates. Try something like this ChartAreas[0].AxisX.IntervalType = DateTimeIntervalType.Days; // or .Month or something

Comment: I changed the function to `Points.AddXY()`. I checked also that the data converts successfully. Only I have problems with the second for. I'll edit my question